# Delayed Job converting time, giving weird mocha expectation error

Tags: datetime, delayed-job

I'm not sure if you guys test like this, but I'm a TDD guy and keep stumbling into wierd stuff. The timestamps are converted somehow by DJ, or the time zone... I don't know. Test example follows

I'm using delayed_job 2.0.3

```
data = {:value => 0.856, :timestamp => Time.zone.now}
job = MyMailer.send_later :send_values, data, emails

MyMailer.expects(:send_values).with(data, emails).once
job.payload_object.perform

class MyMailer
  def self.send_values(data, emails)

  end
end
```

OK, test expectation failure

```
unexpected invocation: MyMailer.send_values({:value => 0.856576407208833, :timestamp => Thu Nov 11 22:01:00 UTC 2010 (1289512860.94962 secs)}, ..
unsatisfied expectations:
- expected exactly once, not yet invoked:  MyMailer.send_values({:value => 0.856576407208833, :timestamp => Thu, 11 Nov 2010 23:01:00 CET +01:00}...
```

with datetime it's similar, `DateTime.now` instead of `Time.zone.now`

```
got      :timestamp => Thu Nov 11 23:13:33 +0100 2010 (1289513613.0 secs)
expected :timestamp => 2010-11-11T23:13:33+01:00
```

What's happening? How can I control it (do I want to)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I had the answer to this when I first saw the question. But I don't anymore, so here is a guess:

Since Time.zone.now, DateTime.now and Time.now are slightly different from each other, and Zone is something Rails has created (I think), could it be that ruby somewhere in your testing framework misses out on the zone-thingy? Time.zone.now.to_datetime has rescued me from similar stuff before. It lets you use zone, and you get the same format as DateTime.now witch lacks DateTime.zone.now.

```
Try: data = {:value => 0.856, :timestamp => Time.zone.now.to_datetime}
```

Comment: you're definitely right about the time zone being the problem, but it's not a problem at insertion time, it's a problem when DJ deserializes the yaml (the handler), not using the configured Time.zone, only the server Time zone (which is the same as Time.now)

Comment: yes I see - but would that not be correct if you adjust Time.zone.now to Time.zone.now.to_datetime, prior to your insertion?